# Paragraph with overflow-y:scroll is displacing my downside Div

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph inside a Div.I have fixed the width and height of paragraph alongwith this property `overflow-y:scroll` .Its Ok that my paragraph is coming with vertical Scroll .But it is displacing my below Div.

Here is the HTML..

```
<div id="bodydesc" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px; height: 600px;">
    <p id="desc"  style="float:left;overflow-y: scroll;color: #666666;height:590px; width:700px; font-family: Candara,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border-right: thin dotted #666666; line-height: 18px;"></p>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="footer-shadow">
    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px; "></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for class footer-shadow..

```
.footer-shadow{
    background-image: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.jpg');
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    color: gray;
}
```

My This Div `<div id="footer" class="footer-shadow">` is going down means displacing from its original position..

Please help me..

Comment: If possible provide a demo of you code. You can use [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/). It will be helpful to understand you problem.

Comment: You should use css separately from your html, here is a present: http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/HM8et/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with checking your html syntax.  Make sure you'r html is correct first and that you close and open your `<div></div>` tags properly.

Once you've checked that I think you need to add `float:left` to your `.footer-shadow` style.  Without it I think it's wrapping the html onto the next line.

Comment: I checked and as per my understanding its OK

Comment: See amendment to my answer,  I would also advise keeping your styles in a style sheet and not using in-line element styles if you can help it.  This makes it harder to manage and debug if you have issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a fixed size to the div containing the `overflow-y` attribute in pixels.